# How to use Google Analytics with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

In my `react` app I have some pages:

1. Main
2. Service
3. Contact
4. Profile (private)
5. etc..

I need to track users activity with Google Analytics. I googled [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) and it's just fine. But with this library I have to initialize my GA on every route I use. For example:

Route "/" - main page:

```
class Main extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        initGA();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Component1 />
                <Component2 />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My `initGA()` looks like:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

export const initGA = () => {
    ReactGA.initialize('UA-00000000-1');
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
    console.log(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}
```

My `App class` looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">

                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                        <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupLayout} />
                        <Route component={PublicLayout} />
                    </Switch>

                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

In my way of using `react-ga` I'm adding `initGA()` function on every component which renders on route response. I think it is not right to duplicate `initGA()` in every component. Please, guys, how do you use `react-ga`? What is right way to use react-ga?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make it work need to use `Router` functionality.
So in App component `import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'`. It has to be Router not BrowserRouter.

Then `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'`

```
const history = createHistory()
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-1');
history.listen((location, action) => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
    console.log(location.pathname)
});
```

This code will fire on every route change!

Than give a history attribute to your Router component.

Complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import Main from './components/pages/Main';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';


const history = createHistory()
ReactGA.initialize('UA-00000000-1');
history.listen((location, action) => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
    console.log(location.pathname)
});

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <Router history={history}>
                <div className="App">

                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                        <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupLayout} />
                        <Route component={PublicLayout} />
                    </Switch>

                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So using this, we don't need call initGA() on every component in componentDidMount() / componentWillMount() ?

Comment: This answer is ok, but you won't save the first page load in the analytics. The `history.listen` will fire only when the route changes. This doesn't happen when you first load the page.

Comment: (not related to the question) but please don't create classes if you don't need them. Use a functional component instead. I personally love using `class`, but only when I need it.

Comment: @slinden old comment, but maybe could help others: to register also the first page load just fire up the ReactGA.pageview function right after ReactGA.initialize, thats all

Answer (score 13):

This is the way to do it with hooks.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_GA_TRACKING_NO)
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory()
browserHistory.listen((location, action) => {
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search)
})

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
  }, [])

  return <div>Test</div>
}
```

The answer above with the class components is almost fine, but you won't get to see the first page load in the analytics. The `history.listen` will fire only when the route changes. This doesn't happen when you first load the page. To fix this, I added a `useEffect` a hook in the `App` component. If the user reloads the site, the `App` will be always rerendered. `ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)` makes sure that we attribute the reload to the correct route if the route is something else than `'/'`.

Comment: are you sure this works? Looks like `useEffect` will only be called once!

Comment: It has to called only once. The hook records only the FIRST page load. The rest of the page loads will be recorded in the `browserHistory.listen` even listener.

Comment: I used your solution and it works great for me. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution utilising [useLocation()](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/) released in React Router V5.1.

The benefit of this approach is that it is compatible with `BrowserRouter` if you wish to continue using that.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation,} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

// Init Google Analytics
ReactGA.initialize('UA-00000000-1');

const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  // Fired on every route change
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className="App"></div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest implementation that works comprehensively at this point, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should only init once, and then after that use

```
ReactGA.pageview(pagepath);
```

in your routing.

Demo: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/tree/master/demo

Comment: What do you mean "in your routing"? Can you give more detailed example with code?

Comment: In this way tracking doesn't work. Gives a warning: react-ga.js:88 [react-ga] ReactGA.initialize must be called first or GoogleAnalytics should be loaded manually

Comment: i added `ReactGA.initialize` on index.js and on every page `ReactGA.pageview('...')` but there is always an alert on console `ReactGA.initialize must be called first or GoogleAnalytics should be loaded manually`. So i decided to add on every page `ReactGA.initialize`

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem using service.js file where you have to made multiple expotrs

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

export const GAInit = (TrackingID) => {
   ReactGA.initialize(TrackingID)
}

export const GAEvent = (category, action) => {
ReactGA.initialize('TrackingIDHere')   
ReactGA.event({
   category,
   action
})
}

// export pageview and more...
```

import from App.js and initialize and use services you wouldn't need to initialize  everytime.

or you can use script instead of react-ga to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting the paths (always '/') until I realised I was using HashRouter. If this is the case, then you can apply the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, NavLink, HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

const App = () => {
   ReactGA.initialize(trackingId);
   const browserHistory = createHashHistory();
   browserHistory.listen((location, action) => {
      ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
})

// Activate Google Analytics
useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}, []);
}
```

By the way, it is not recommended to put your Google Analytics tracking_id on the client-side. Below is the updated code in a more secure way, using axios to retrieve the tracking_id from the server:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const getTrackingID = async () => {
            await axios.get(`${url}/ga/tracking_id`, {
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 204) {
                    console.log('No GA tracking_id found');
                } else if (res.status === 200) {
                    const trackingId = res.data;
                    ReactGA.initialize(trackingId);
                    // Capture 1st load in home page
                    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
                    // Capture any subsequent page change
                    browserHistory.listen((location) => {
                        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error while retrieving GA tracking_id', err);
            });
       };
       getTrackingID();
   }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you solve avoiding to "initialize" GA on every component.

Basically, make sure that the first ReactGA script that runs is `ReactGA.initialize('UA-00000000-1');`

To ensure that you should place your `initGA();` outside of `componentDidMount()`, and keep the rest of your ReactGA scripts inside of `componentDidMount()`.

I know it is an old post but all of the answers addressed route tracking but not this actual issue.