# How do I use Google Analytics with react-router v5 and StaticRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I am trying to add  Google Analytics with react-router v5 StaticRouter in my React SSR app
as suggested in [How to use Google Analytics with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724447/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-react). I understand createBrowserHistory doesn't work so thought I will use createMemoryHistory. Seems the removed createMemoryHistory in v4? I would try to listen to route change in but couldn't figure out how to do that with SSR? Or I could write a HOC and fix it. But it seems this a bit cleaner and easier way to do it.

Now to achieve something like this, how do I do it?

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

ReactGA.initialize('UA-*********-1');


const history = createMemoryHistory();
history.listen(location => {
  console.log('location', location);
  ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
});

function NotFound() {
  return <h1>Oops, nothing here!</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(({ path, component, isPublic, exact }) => (
          isPublic ?
            <Route
              key={path}
              exact={exact}
              path={path}
              component={component}
              history={history}
            />
            :
            <ProtectedRoute
              isLoggedIn={user}
              key={path}
              path={path}
              component={component}
              exact={exact}
              public={false}
              history={history}
            />
        ))}
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>)
  );
}
```