# Google Analytics with react-ga library

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I put in the initialization code, but it only runs once for one page. How do I get the google tracker to fire for multiple pages in the app?

In App.js

```
 ReactGA.initialize("UA-XXXXXXXXX-1");
 let baseUrl = window.location.pathname;
 ReactGA.pageview(baseUrl);
```

Comment: You can try to use events right?

Comment: This link might help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724447/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Google Analytics with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724447/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-react)

Answer (score 0):

I recommand 2 different options:

1. Add the google tracker in the navigation bar (or footer). It will renders in every page.
2. Create a custom component and put on every rendered page.