# Google Analytics with react and react router

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router-v4, google-analytics-4, react-ga

I have been trying to integrate Google analytics in my react app and i used every way mentioned on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724447/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-react) and all solutions are failing. Below are the methods i tried and the corresponding error i am getting. Hope someone can help

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import store from './Store';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import MobileMenu from './components/layout/MobileMenu';
import Tutorial from './components/layout/Tutorial';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
ReactGA.initialize('G-11111111');
history.listen((location, action) => {
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
  console.log(location.pathname);
});
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/tutorial" component={Tutorial} />
              </Switch>
              <MobileMenu />
              <Footer />
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The first page loads normally but if i click on any link from my Switch i get a blank page and the following warning

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2450 [react-ga] path is required in .pageview()
```

Second method i tried with hooks i get same error

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import store from './Store';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import MobileMenu from './components/layout/MobileMenu';
import Tutorial from './components/layout/Tutorial';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';


const history = createBrowserHistory();
ReactGA.initialize('G-11111111');

history.listen((location, action) => {
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
});

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/tutorial" component={Tutorial} />
              </Switch>
              <MobileMenu />
              <Footer />
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Third way i tried using useLocation() and no history

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import store from './Store';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useLocation
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import MobileMenu from './components/layout/MobileMenu';
import Tutorial from './components/layout/Tutorial';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';



const history = createBrowserHistory();
ReactGA.initialize('G-11111111');


const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  // Fired on every route change
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
  }, [location]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/tutorial" component={Tutorial} />
              </Switch>
              <MobileMenu />
              <Footer />
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it depends on whether you are using a Google Analytics 4 Property ID (G-XXXXXXXX), while the React Analytics package in question works for Universal Analytics. I suggest you create a Universal Analytics Property (as shown in following image) and use the relative identifier UA-XXXXXXX-X:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Michele.
I created a new property and got a UA ID and tried it. Same results. I think the issue i am facing is beyond the GA4. The error i am getting is related to path which is called after initiation. Also all components outside the switch are working fine and every route inside the switch is returning blank page except the first loaded page.