# Google Workspace Addon Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-workspace

I read the google help for tracking an addon (https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/use-analytics)  and I am not sure, what to do on the google analytics side of the idea.

I added a stream and entered the url of the application url, which I can find in the sore entry settings of the google cloud plattform.

Then I entered the Stream ID in the configuration of my addon's store entry configuration page, where it asks for google Analytics-ID (I entered the G- ... number).

But I don't see any data in GA.

What did I get wrong in the first place? :)

Maybe I am on the wrong path, so I want to share my goal as well: I try to track three things of my google calendar add-on:

1. how often the add-on in the Marketplace is viewed
2. how often the add-on actually was installed
3. what the user did in the add-on, while using it.

thanks for your input and questions to lead me to the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a Universal Analytics Property, the one with ID like UA-XXXXX-Y. When you create a new property activate the advanced options and choose that property type.

Comment: and what about the url? was that a right approach?
What is "that" type? can you be more specific, or am I overreading something?

Comment: "That" Property... the only one I mentioned: Universal Analytics Property. Try to see this post to understand how to create it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644897/google-analytics-with-react-and-react-router/64646819#64646819

Comment: Where do I find it? I only have a stream ID and a Measure Id nad a property Id. 
There are no Advanced Options...

Comment: Now I got it. I cannot change a property. I need to know that befor creation. Why is that no  default configuration anymore? What problems will I have in the future with that? will it be deprecated once?

Comment: You have to create a new Property. It will be deprecated in several years, in fact Google suggests to track with both because the new one is still unripe.

Comment: I found that but still the tracking does not work. It might be the other side... do you track any Google workspace addons yourself and can you tell me how you did it?

Comment: When you configure in the Marketplace isn't there a field where you have to enter the Google Analytics property?

Comment: yes I entered it there. But what url do I need to use in GA? Can you go throgh the process with an example of one of your addons?

Comment: The url in the creation of the Property / View in GA is not important, put one at random, it does not have the slightest influence on the collected data.

Comment: Ok I guess it took some time ... thanks for your patience